# Including Module Source files into War file using Maven

Tags: java, web-applications, maven

My goal is to include modules sources files into War file.

I read this explanation on the maven official site:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-source-inclusion-simple.html

I wonder if it's the only way to include all sources files contained within all modules.

Can't the simple maven-plugin-war do the same ?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but is more suited to StackOverflow since it is not about programming but rather seeks a technical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven plugins for packaging can be confusing to work with. You could write a small ANT script and call it from a plugin execution. I sometimes do this if I have complex packaging requirements. It's not elegant, but it gives you full control of the packaging process.